# RegEx for JavaScript validation of comma separated numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one text box and it can have values like `1` or `1,2` or `1,225,345,21` (i.e., multiple values). But now I want to validate this input.

```
toString().match(/^(([0-9](,)?)*)+$/)
```

This is the code I'm using. It is validating correct only, but one problem when the user enters values like this:

```
inputval:1,22,34,25,645(true)
inputval:1,22,34,25,645,(false)
```

When the user enters a comma (`,`) at the end, it should throw an error.

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 26):

Just manually include at least one:

```
/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/
```

```js
let regex = /[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*/g

console.log('1231232,12323123,122323',regex.test('1231232,12323123,122323')); 
console.log('1,22,34,25,645,',regex.test('1,22,34,25,645,'));
console.log('1',regex.test('1'));
```

Comment: Running the same regex test multiple times results in [different results](https://jsfiddle.net/pz05o7fh/). What am I meeting here?

Comment: @Himanshu "JavaScript RegExp objects are stateful when they have the global or sticky flags set (e.g., /foo/g or /foo/y). They store a lastIndex from the previous match. Using this internally, test() can be used to iterate over multiple matches in a string of text (with capture groups)." from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 5):

Variants on the Ariel's Regex :-)

```
/^(([0-9]+)(,(?=[0-9]))?)+$/
```

The `,` must be followed by a digit `(?=[0-9])`.

Or

```
/^(([0-9]+)(,(?!$))?)+$/
```

The `,` must not be followed by the end of the string `(?!$)`.

```
/^(?!,)(,?[0-9]+)+$/
```

We check that the first character isn't a `,` `(?!,)` and then we put the optional `,` before the digits. It's optional because the first block of digits doesn't need it.

Comment: I'd drop the `(x+y?)+` pattern entirely - it easily leads to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: @Kobi As always, what you can do and what you should do with regexes are quite different :-)