# Regex for comma separated numbers within specific range

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex that validated the comma separated numbers with min and max number limit. i tried this regex but no luck

```
^(45|[1-9][0-5]?)$
```

i want the list like this one (min number is 1 and max number is 45)

```
23,45,3,7,1,9,34
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944065/regex-for-javascript-validation-of-comma-separated-numbers or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620980/comma-separated-numbers-regex or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960858/regex-javascript-numbers-comma-separated

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a job for regex (regex are not handy with numbers, imagine the same with a more complicated range like (247,69352) that needs to build a giant pattern). So my advice is to split your string and then to check your items one by one.

A way without regex:

```
function numsInRange(s, min, max) {
    var items = s.split(',');
    for (var i in items) {
        var num = parseInt(items[i], 10);
        if (num != items[i] || num < min || num > max)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var s='23,45,3,7,1,9,34';

console.log(numsInRange(s, 1, 45)); // true
console.log(numsInRange(s, 1, 44)); // false
```

[demo](https://eval.in/462988)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do the job:

```
\b(([1-3][0-9])|(4[0-5])|[1-9])\b
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to use a combination of regex (depending on need) and array iterators (not `for..in` enumeration) (ES5 in example)

```js
var reIsPattern = /^[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)$/;

function areNumsInRange(commaString, min, max) {
  return commaString.split(',')
    .map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim)
    .every(function(item) {
      return reIsPattern.test(item) && item >= min && item <= max
    });
}

var s = '23,45,3,7,1,9,34';

document.body.textContent = areNumsInRange(s, 1, 45);
```

Or perhaps just simply

```js
function areNumsInRange(commaString, min, max) {
  return commaString.split(',').every(function(item) {
    var num = Number(item);
    return num >= min && num <= max;
  });
}

var s = '23,45,3,7,1,9,34';

document.body.textContent = areNumsInRange(s, 1, 45);
```